# .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width:_,height:_)) not working in Xcode 14

Tags: swiftui, xcode14

Since updating to Xcode 14 the SwiftUI canvas is behaving differently.

I'm have files that are a fixed size and I am trying to preview them by adding

`.previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width: width,height: height))`

to the preview view.

Previously the behaviour was that I would see the canvas the expected width of view.  Now I'm seeing the preview in a device.

Is there a way I can get this to work as expected again?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Xcode 14 preview loads default in Live mode but you can change this to selectable, by clicking the second button from the bottom toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set "selectable" as the default to use when a preview loads?

Comment: @gooberwonder I have look for it but not able to find a way to make selectable as the default